# Dynamically capture output of system command in Perl

Tags: perl, glade

In my Perl code, I use a system command to run a script. I'm using Gtk2::Perl and Glade to build a UI. I need the output of the command to be captured not just to the console (which `Capture::Tiny` does), but also to a TextView in my GUI.

```
system("command");

$stdout = tee{                         #This captures the output to the console
system("command");  
};

$textbuffer->set_text($stdout);       #This does set the TextView with the captured output, but *after* the capture is over.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: I need the output of `system` to be captured in the TextView simultaneously with its capture on the console. That's not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to 'capture' the output of a `system` call, then I would suggest the best approach is to use `open` and open a filehandle to your process:

```
my $pid = open ( my $process_output, '-|', "command" );
```

Then you can read `$process_output` exactly as you would a file handle (bear in mind it'll block if there's no IO pending).

```
while ( <$process_output> ) { 
   print; 
}

close ( $process_output );
```

You can 'fake' the behaviour of `system` via the `waitpid` system call:

```
 waitpid ( $pid, 0 );
```

This will 'block' your main program until the system call has completed.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose the use of `open` is my best bet. Will do this!

Comment: This is very useful but does not really solve my problem, actually - the output is not *dynamically* updated in the TextView as it is generated. There is a distinct delay, sadly.

Comment: Look up autoflush in the IO::handle docs. Open like this is already running in a parallel process.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not possible with `system()`. `System()` forks a new process *and* waits for it to terminate. Then your program continues (see [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)). You could start a sub-process (executing whatever `system()` did for you) and read this sub-process' stdout. You could for example get inspired here: [redirecting stdin/stdout from exec'ed process to pipe in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295250/redirecting-stdin-stdout-from-execed-process-to-pipe-in-perl)

Comment: Ah, I see. I expected to be able to do something with system(), as this capture is the only thing lacking. Thanks a lot!